# How to scroll a particular control into view when it is on a TableLayoutPanel in a Panel

Tags: winforms, panel, autoscroll, tablelayoutpanel

My TableLayoutPanel contains a varying number of custom user-controls, depending on the size of the list of items it needs to display. Sometimes the list is quite long, and users would like a way to scroll directly or "jump" to a control using a CTRL-F style search, more or less.

So far, I haven't been able to get this work using the `ScrollControlIntoView` method, and would appreciate some tips. In the test code below, the `Find` method does not find the control whose name is "uc3", one of the custom-user-controls which has been placed on the TableLayoutPanel, even though the Find method's search-child-controls parameter is set to `true`.

> NOTE: I've confirmed that uc3 has indeed been created. In my test,
>   there are only three such controls, and all three are visible on
>   screen, and I've stepped through the code and seen them as they get
>   created, and as their names get assigned.

```
var ctl = this.splitContainerControl1.Panel2.Controls.Find("uc3", true);
if (ctl.Length> 0)      this.splitContainerControl1.Panel2.ScrollControlIntoView(ctl[0]);
```

I'm invoking the `ScrollControlIntoView` method from the simple Panel (Panel2) because it is the one which is set to AutoScroll. The TableLayoutPanel has that property set to `false`:

```
var skedcontainer = new VideoScheduleContainer(); // inherits from TableLayoutPanel
skedcontainer.Dock = DockStyle.Top;
skedcontainer.AutoSize = true;
skedcontainer.AutoSizeMode = AutoSizeMode.GrowAndShrink;
skedcontainer.AutoScroll = false; 
skedcontainer.DataSource = SCHEDULEDVIDEOS.AsDataView();           
this.splitContainerControl1.Panel2.AutoScroll = true;
this.splitContainerControl1.Panel2.AutoSize = false;
this.splitContainerControl1.Panel2.Controls.Add(skedcontainer);
```

Comment: `the Find method does not find the control whose name is "uc3"`  That's really the issue, not the scrolling.  You would have to show how that UserControl is getting created and added to the table.

Comment: Agreed. I'll add a note to the question.

Comment: It would help us help you if you showed the code that creates and adds those controls to your container.  That the Find method returns nothing means something is not correct with how you are adding your controls.

Comment: Can you show us the code that set the user controls names ?